# i18n localisation not working in nodejs build version

Tags: node.js, localization, internationalization, i18next

I have a node js project and added the [i18n](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) package from  for localization and it worked great in dev,

But when I run the same project from dist folder, all JSON files are empty.

I have a `locales` folder in src folder which contain `en_*us.json` and `de*de.json`.
when I run after npm build, I see the locales folder with both JSON file but both are empty.

I think this is an issue related to typescript or directory issue, please can anyone check.

Here is the code.

```
import i18n from 'i18n';
import path from 'path';
import { setLocale } from './config/locale/locale.js';

  /**  Localization   */
  const __dirname = path.dirname(new URL(import.meta.url).pathname);
  /** Configure localization */
  i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en_us', 'de_de'],
    defaultLocale: 'en_us',
    directory: __dirname + '/locales',
  });
  app.use(i18n.init);
  app.use(setLocale);

  // routes
  app.get('/', async function (req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.json({ message: i18n.__('server-running') });
  });
  app.use(routes);
  app.use('*', notFoundHandler);
  app.use(errorHandler);
```

I tried with a different path and did't work.

I am expecting same JSON file with content should be there in dist folder as well

Answer (score 1):

You will have to copy the locales json file in dist folder to make it work.
You could add this process while running the build.

1. Add package to copy files

```
npm install --save-dev copyfiles
```

2. in package.json script add

```
    "build": "tsc && copyfiles -u 1 -e \"**/*.ts\" \"./src/locales/**/*.json\" \"./dist\" --flatten",
```

this will copy locales folder in src/locales to your dist folder.